# Flutter iOS available camera empty array

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, simulator, hybrid

my question is whether I have to do any additional steps in order to get a list of available cameras on iOS.
Even when following the docs and trying examples from other online resources, I can't seem to get a list of available cameras.

Here's the code. It's super basic but still doesn't give me any cameras.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera:
```

I've placed the dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` file

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,146ms.
flutter: []
```

The output is simply an empty array.

```java
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(CameraApp());

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      print(availableCameras);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Text('Hello, World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing it on real iOS device, because I guess iOS simulator don't support cameras. You have to use real physical device.

Comment: Oh... wow, that's quite disappointing, I saw an answer from 2014 which stated that the camera is not simulated.

But you're right, just set up an android emulator and I'm getting a list of cameras now.

Thank you very much, was not expecting this.

Comment: The iOS Simulator doesn't support the usage of cameras

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've added this in `ios/Runner/Info.plist` to be able to access the camera and mic, as mentioned on this [camera setup guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#1-add-the-required-dependencies).

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explanation on why the camera access is needed.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explanation on why the microphone access is needed.</string>
```

Also, accessing the camera is not supported when running the app on iOS Simulator as mentioned in [Apple docs](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d). You'll need a physical iOS device for that.